# Avoiding overflow in log(cosh(x))

Tags: python, numpy, numeric, logarithm, hyperbolic-function

My simulation needs to implement

```
np.log(np.cosh(x))
```

This overflows for large `x`, i. e. I'm getting the `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in cosh` warning. In principle, as logarithm decreases the number in question, in some range of `x`, `cosh` should overflow while `log(cosh())` should not.

Is there any solution for that in NumPy, for example similar in spirit to the `np.log1p()` function?

To provide more info: I am aware that a possible solution might be symbolic using SymPy
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12671
however the simulation should be fast, and symbolic calculation AFAIK might slow it down significantly.

Comment: what is your `dtype` set to?

Comment: It is np.complex128 (and needs to handle complex numbers indeed).

Comment: Was about to suggest the identity `log(cosh(x)) = logaddexp(x, -x) - log(2)` until I saw the comment about complex numbers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following implementation of `log(cosh(x))` should be numerically stable:

```py
import numpy as np

def logcosh(x):
    # s always has real part >= 0
    s = np.sign(x) * x
    p = np.exp(-2 * s)
    return s + np.log1p(p) - np.log(2)
```

**Explanation:**

For real values you could use the following identity:

```
log(cosh(x)) = logaddexp(x, -x) - log(2)
             = abs(x) + log1p(exp(-2 * abs(x))) - log(2)
```

which is numerically stable because the argument to `exp` is always non-positive. For complex numbers we instead require that the argument to `exp` has **non-positive real part**, which we achieve by using `-x` when `real(x) > 0` and `x` otherwise.